# Scrapy get downloaded file name

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy, please bear with me.

I have a spider that visits a page, and downloads a file.
Ultimately I want to write the name of the file, along with other useful information to a db table.

--> Right now, I am struggling to get the file name:

from items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class NdrItem(scrapy.Item):
    district = Field()
    file_urls = Field()
    file_name = Field()
    files = Field()
```

from spider:

```
import scrapy
from ndr.items import NdrItem

class CentralBedfordshireSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'central_bedfordshire2'
    allowed_domains = ['centralbedfordshire.gov.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://centralbedfordshire.gov.uk/business/rates/paying/published.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):

        relative_url = response.xpath("//article[@class='page-content__article']/div[@class='editor']/p[3]/a/@href").extract_first()
        download_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)
        item = NdrItem()
        item['district'] = 'central bedfordshire'
        item['file_urls'] = [download_url]
        print('------------------ Print the info I want to eventually go in db --------------------------')
        print(item['district'])
        print(item['files'])
    return item
```

Edit: The file is downloading ok and has the sha1 filename when downloaded.  I would like to have the sha1 filename.

Edit: I get the following error when I run this spider:

```html
2017-08-22 10:39:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://centralbedfordshire.gov.uk/business/rates/paying/published.aspx> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\MichaelAnderson\GDrive\Python\ndr\ndr\spiders\central_bedfordshire2.py", line 19, in parse
    print(item['files'])
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 59, in __getitem__
    return self._values[key]
KeyError: 'files'
```

Typically if people have a number of spiders all saving data to the same folder, how do people reference downloaded files and keep them linked to the source URL?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: What are you expecting for a filename?

Comment: Added the info - cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific requirement, I would probably use Scrapy [Files Pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-files-pipeline) together with custom pipeline ordered after the Files Pipeline. From the Files Pipeline documentation:

> When the files are downloaded, another field (`files`) will be populated with the results. This field will contain a list of dicts with information about the downloaded files, such as the downloaded path, the original scraped url (taken from the `file_urls` field) , and the file checksum. The files in the list of the `files` field will retain the same order of the original `file_urls` field. If some file failed downloading, an error will be logged and the file won’t be present in the `files` field.

In your spider, populate the field `file_urls` with file locations you wish to download. Then, after processing the item with standard Files Pipeline, it will contain field `files` with SHA1 filenames for each of the location in `file_urls`, in the same order. Then write another custom pipeline, which will process items after Files Pipeline and will use this information.

Comment: Brilliant - this is exactly what I'm after.  I have tried to print the item 'files' but it is not working.  See error above.

Comment: @RedBeard You are trying to print `files` field in `parse` method, but it isn't present there yet. The item first has to pass the Files Pipeline which will add that field. First put locations of files to download into `file_urls` field in your `parse` method. Then, activate Files Pipeline in your settings. Next, write your custom pipeline (order after Files Pipeline) to process items with already present `files` fields.

Comment: Wrote a custom pipeline to print 'files' and it works great - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to get it from the URL itself. If you use Python 3 below will work

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = "http://centralbedfordshire.gov.uk/Images/business-rates-live-account-list-2017-07_tcm3-9033.csv"

print(urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
'business-rates-live-account-list-2017-07_tcm3-9033.csv'
```

**Edit-1**

If you need to get SHA1 hash

```
import hashlib
sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
sha1.update(url.encode("utf-8"))
sha1_hash = sha1.hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm after the sha1 filename please..from the docs https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html "The files are stored using a SHA1 hash of their URLs for the file names."